# Acts_as_indexed .with_query() não retorna os resultados esperados na query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4

Boa tarde,
tenho um método para buscar produtos no banco que usa o método with_query da gem acts_as_indexed:

Produto.with_query(query_texto)

Isso esta gerando uma query SQL  assim:

SELECT  `produtos`.* FROM `produtos` WHERE (produtos.id IN (NULL)) LIMIT 11

Já testei substituindo o .with_query(query_texto) por .all e os resultados são retornados. Já verifiquei no meu model produtos.rb tenho configurado os campos para  gem funcionar (acts_as_indexed :fields => [ :status, :nome ]).

Alguém tem alguma idéia de porque a gem esta retornando  WHERE (produtos.id IN (NULL)) na query? 
Obrigado.

obs o mesmo ocorre pelo console

Produto.with_query('Pump')

Produto Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `produtos`.* FROM `produtos` WHERE (produtos.id IN (NULL)) LIMIT 11

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi solucionado dando um update em todos os produtos. Pelo visto essa gem cria algum tipo de index quando o item é atualizado.

Fiz isso no rails console:

```html
Produto.all.each do |produto|
    nome = produto.nome
    Produto.update(produto.id, :nome => 'teste')
    Produto.update(produto.id, :nome => nome )
end
```